# Union and intersection of sets in roster form

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a set of all $(x,y)$ which belong to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ while $B$ is a set of all $(x,y)$ which belong to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $x$ and $y$ both are equal to or greater than $-1$ and equal to or less than $1$ then what are

$$A \cup B,$$
and
$$A \cap B?$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Remark : I use R² to denote " R cross R" ( the cartesian product of R by itself)

Use symbolab to visualize the sets in question :

https://www.symbolab.com/graphing-calculator

A = { (x,y) belonging to R²| x²+y² = 1}

The set A is the circle of center (O,O) and of radius 1.

B = { (x,y) belonging to R²| x belongs to [-1; 1]  and y belongs to [-1;1] }

The set B is the area  enclosed in the parallel vertical lines x=1, x=-1, and the parallel horizontal lines y=-1 and y=1. I let you determine what is this area and in which figure it is enclosed.

A Union B = { (x,y) belonging to R²| x²+y² = 1 OR  x and y belong to [-1; 1] }

A Union B is the set of all points ( x, y) that belong to the circle OR to the aforementionned area ( or to both of them). Remark : in the definition of " union" the " or" is the inclusive or ( inclusive disjunction).

A Inter B = { (x,y) belonging to R²| x²+y² = 1 AND   x and y belong to [-1; 1] }

A Inter B is the set of points (x,y) that belong **both** to the circle **and** to the aforementionned area .

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution